# Find maximum points of a integral function

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, maxima-minima

I am solving this exercice:

---

Let $I_0$ a neighbourhood of $0$, let $g\in C^1(I_0)$ such that $g(0)<0$. Define
$$
f_\beta(x)=\int_{\sin(x)-\beta x}^{x^2} g(y)\,dy\,\,\,\, \forall \beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Find the values of $\beta$ such that $x_0=0$  is a (local) maximum for $f_\beta$.

---

I started with
$$
f'_\beta(x)=2xg(x^2)-(\cos(x)-\beta)g(\sin(x)-\beta x)
$$
requiring $f'_\beta(0)=0$ I get $\beta=1$. (is it correct?)

Then let $I_0^-$  a left neighbourhood of $0$,  I have $2xg(x^2)>0$ and $-(\cos(x)-1)g(\sin(x)- x)<0$, so I cannot say that $f'_1>0$ in $I_0^-$, that was my guess.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$ g $ is continuous at $ x_0=0 $, and $ g(0)<0 \implies $

$$(\exists \eta>0)\;:\: g((-\eta,\eta))\subset (-\infty,0)$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin(x)-x))=0\implies $$
$$(\exists \delta_1>0)\;:\; (\forall x\in(-\delta_1,\delta_1)) \;$$
$$\sin(x)-x\in(-\eta,\eta)$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^2=0\implies$$
$$(\exists \delta_2>0)\;:\;\forall x\in(-\delta_2,\delta_2)\;$$
$$ x^2\in(-\eta,\eta)$$

Put $ \delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

then
$$\forall x\in(-\delta,\delta)$$
$$[\sin(x)-x,x^2]\subset(-\eta,\eta)$$

from here, you can prove that $ f_1(x)\le 0$.

Comment: thanks. Can you explain how prove that $f_1\leq 0$?. What can you say about the sign of $f'$?